# Wit ai example code error null buffer length

Tags: node.js

I tried to get started with Wit ai by run its example code.
So I tried:

`$node examples/template.js <my_server_token>` (`my_server_token` is replaced with my actual Wit server token).

It generated error

```
string_decoder.js:66
var buflen = buffer.length;

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
    at StringDecoder.write (string_decoder.js:66:22)
    at Interface._normalWrite (readline.js:319:30)
    at Interface.write (readline.js:310:49)
    at message.converse.makeActionCallback.runActions.interactive.rl.on [as interactive] (D:\R&D\witai\node_modules\node-wit\lib\wit.js:286:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (\witai\node_modules\node-wit\examples\template.js:29:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
```

Does someone face same problem and solve it?

Comment: Opened a new issue here https://github.com/wit-ai/node-wit/issues/41

Comment: Same here - node.js in Heroku

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exact reason.
It's OK when I tried on windows command line but failed on Cygwin.
The above error generated when I tried on Cygwin.